# Returning more than one page in Python Twitter search

Tags: python, twitter

So I'm trying to run a search query through the Twitter API in Python. I can get it to return up to 100 results using the "count" parameter. Unfortunately, version 1.1 doesn't seem to have the "page" parameter that was present in 1.0. Is there some sort of alternative for 1.1? Or, if not, does anyone have any suggestions for alternative ways to get a decent amount of tweets returned for a subject.

Thanks.

Update with solution:

Thanks to the Ersin below.

I queried as a normally would for a page, and when it's return I would check for the id of the oldest tweet. I'd then use this as the max_id in the next URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use "since_id" parameter in your url. since_id provides u getting pages that older than since_id. So, for the next page you should set the since_id parameter as the last id of your current page.

Comment: you are welcome and I aprreciate if you sign this post as a valid answer.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late reply. Consider yourself valid and thanks again. I'll update the main post with my implementation.